# Grails ajax get firing success and error

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I'm trying to get data from my url `http://localhost:8080/test/rest/info`, which is json

```
[{"id":1,"name":"abc","age":12,"city":"la"}]
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossdomain: true,
    url: "http://localhost:8080/test/rest/info",
    success: success(),
    error: fail()
});

function success(data){
    alert(data);
}

function error(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(textStatus);
}
```

success and error methods are firing, but they are returning data undefined and after is a error, where I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a function reference, not execute the function:

```
success: success,
error: fail
```

Comment: if I want to execute the function should be like `success: function() {};`?

Comment: That won't execute the function, it will pass the reference to the anonymous function.

Comment: Ok, it worked, but it's on going fail function, you have any thoughts of not getting my url json?

Comment: Any errors in your console? Do the request and response look right?

Comment: from  `textStatus` and `errorThrown` are only giving me `error` on console.

Comment: I can access the url no problem, it returning me json.